# Model as an algorithm/processing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I'd like to know if it is possible to use a model (previously made by the graphical modeler of QGIS) as algorithm/processing in the flow of another model.

Comment: Yes, that it is possible! ;)

Comment: Ok, how can i do this? Any suggestions? Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a model and save it.
2. In Menu <kbd>Processing</kbd> > <kbd>Toolbox</kbd> click on the Model icon and <kbd>Add Model to Toolbox</kbd>.
3. Open the modeler. The loaded model is now available under <kbd>Algorithms</kbd> > <kbd>Models</kbd>. You can add it to your (new) model as any other algorithm.

[image]